# Find the volume of this improper integral?

Tags: improper-integrals, volume

Find the volume of the described solid of revolution or state that it does not exist.

The region bounded by $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)}{x^3}}$ and the $x$-axis on the interval $[1,\infty)$ is resolved about the $x$-axis

I tried this many times but I keep getting $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps 
$$ V=\pi\int_1^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)}{x^3}}\right)^2 dx$$
$$ =\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty} \int_1^{b}\left|\frac{x+1}{x^3}\right| dx$$
$$ =\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty} \int_1^{b}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}\right) dx$$
$$ =\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty} \int_1^{b}x^{-2}dx+ \pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty} \int_1^{b} x^{-3}dx$$
$$ =-\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}x^{-1}\bigg|_1^{b}-\frac{\pi}{2} \lim\limits_{b\to\infty} x^{-2}\bigg|_1^{b} $$
$$ =-\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\bigg|_1^{b}-\frac{\pi}{2} \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg|_1^{b} $$
$$ =-\pi \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{b}- 1 \right]-\frac{\pi}{2} \lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{b^2}-1\right]$$
$$ =-\pi (0- 1)-\frac{\pi}{2}(0-1)$$
$$ =-\pi (- 1)-\frac{\pi}{2}(-1)$$
$$ =\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

The volume of revolution is formed by rotating $f(x)=\sqrt{(x+1)/x^3}$ around the $x$-axis along $[1,\infty)$. As such, we can proceed with the standard formula,

$$V=\pi \int_1^\infty \! f(x)^2 \, dx = \pi \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3}\right) \, dx =\pi \left( \frac{3}{2} - \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1+2x}{2x^2}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: could you show me the part before π(3/2 - lim (1+2x)/(2x^2)?

Comment: oh i got it ,  you used L'Hospital rule

Comment: @monkey6991 You don't need to use L'Hospital's rule for the limit; $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{-n} = 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @monkey6991 Integrate $x^{-2}$ and $x^{-3}$ using your integral rules $\int x^{n} dx = \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1}$

Comment: then you would have [-1/x - 1/x^2]

Comment: @monkey6991 $\int 1/x^2 + 1/x^3 \, dx = -1/x -1/2x^2$.

Comment: thank you all for your help , it seems i made a mistake  during the integration of 1/x^3 , that's why I couldn't find the solution